# Error 'Notice: trying to get property of non-object' on host's webserver but not on my localhost

Tags: php, json, localhost

I've got the above error message when trying to use the block.io API on my web host's server. The JSON object returns 'success' with an object on my localhost using the exact same script. The PHP version of my localhost is 5.6.10 and on my web host they run 5.5.

Is there any reason for getting the correct response on my localhost but not on the web host's server?

here is my code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('block_io.php');

$apiKey = "my API key";
$version = 2; // API version
$pin = "my password";
$block_io = new BlockIo($apiKey, $pin, $version);

$newAddressInfo = $block_io->get_new_address(array());


var_dump($newAddressInfo);

?>
```

This is the response from my localhost:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["status"]=> string(7) "success" ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["network"]=> string(4) "DOGE" ["user_id"]=> int(27) ["address"]=> string(34) "A7wNbTJYhJb5FYJbg1cYW67fJNRGwXLBiP" ["label"]=> string(7) "quine46" } }
```

This is the response from my hosted script:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/sites/**************.com/public_html/block_io.php on line 121 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed: ' in /home/sites/**************.com/public_html/block_io.php:121 Stack trace: #0 /home/sites/**************.com/public_html/block_io.php(65): BlockIo->_request('get_new_address', Array) #1 /home/sites/**************.com/public_html/block.php(14): BlockIo->__call('get_new_address', Array) #2 /home/sites/**************.com/public_html/block.php(14): BlockIo->get_new_address(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /home/sites/**************.com/public_html/block_io.php on line 121
```

exact same script, different outcome. Any ideas?

Comment: it looks like `new BlockIo($apiKey, $pin, $version);` is not working. You should check the code of that if there is any reason for it to fail on the webhost.

Comment: @DocRattie any idea why it would fail on the web host and not on localhost?

Comment: I don't know what `BlockIO` is. But it's probably somethin in there, that is not set up on the server or is not working for soem reason. Hard to tell without its code.